# JS calculator project help needed to string together several operations and get the right answer

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am having trouble getting past this step in my project. I've gotten it to hold the operator and the numbers,but I can't get it to string together operations. I think it's where the operations and numbers are being stored is where the hiccup is. I can only get my code to do the first operation and it discards all other data.

This is my code so far:

```js
let numIni = "";
let numSub = "";
let op = "";
let display = document.querySelector('#display');
let result = 0;
clr();


//basic addition
function addition(numIni, numSub) {
  return parseFloat(numIni) + parseFloat(numSub);

}

//basic subtraction
function subtraction(numIni, numSub) {
  return parseFloat(numIni) - parseFloat(numSub);
}

//basic Multiplication
function multiply(numIni, numSub) {
  return parseFloat(numIni) * parseFloat(numSub);
}

//basic division
function divide(numIni, numSub) {
    if (numIni == 0 ||numSub == 0) {
        return "Can't do that";
      } 
        return parseFloat(numIni) / parseFloat(numSub);
}

//operator function
function operate(op) {
  switch (op) {
    case "+":
      result = addition(numIni, numSub);
      break;
    case "-":
      result = subtraction(numIni, numSub);
      break;
    case "*":
      result = multiply(numIni, numSub);
      break;
    case "/":
      result = divide(numIni, numSub);
  }
}
//button display functions
function disNum(val) {
  parseFloat(display.value += val);
  

}

function disOp(val) {
  document.getElementById("display").value += val;
  return op = val;
}

function clr() {
  return document.getElementById("display").value = "";
}

function equal() {
  let value = display.value.trim();
  if(value != '') {
    // Separate numbers
    let numbers = [];
    op = '';
    // Is there a valid operator?
    if(value.indexOf('+') != -1) op = '+';
    else if(value.indexOf('-') != -1) op = '-';
    else if(value.indexOf('*') != -1) op = '*';
    else if(value.indexOf('/') != -1) op = '/';
    if(op != '') {
      numbers = value.split(op);
    }
    if(numbers.length == 2) {
      // Set both variables
      numIni = numbers[0];
      numSub = numbers[1];

      operate(op);

      display.value = result;
    } else {
      display.value = 'Error';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <head>Calc</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="display">
        </div>
        
        <input type="button" value="0" onClick="disNum('0')">
        <input type="button" value="1" onClick="disNum('1')">
        <input type="button" value="2" onClick="disNum('2')">
        <input type="button" value="3" onClick="disNum('3')">
        <input type="button" value="4" onClick="disNum('4')">
        <input type="button" value="5" onClick="disNum('5')">
        <input type="button" value="6" onClick="disNum('6')">
        <input type="button" value="7" onClick="disNum('7')">
        <input type="button" value="8" onClick="disNum('8')">
        <input type="button" value="9" onClick="disNum('9')">
        <input type="button" value="+" onClick="disOp('+')">
        <input type="button" value="-" onClick="disOp('-')">
        <input type="button" value="*" onClick="disOp('*')">
        <input type="button" value="/" onClick="disOp('/')">
        <input type="button" value="=" onClick="equal()">
        <input type="button" value="Clr" onClick="clr()">
        <script src= "/home/justin/Calculator/calc.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `result` declared?

Comment: Also, please edit your question and include the relevant HTML and CSS so we can see an executable version of your work and provide you with a working answer.

Comment: Also (FYI), instead of having the basic math operations in their own functions that are largely the same except for the operator, just put the statements into the `switch` in the `operate` function and remove the individual ones. Then `operate` will represent the unit of work that does the math.

Comment: I edited my question to include the html. For some reason my virtual machine is acting strangely. I edited the code to include where result was originally declared. @Scott Marcus

Comment: Can you be clearer as to what the exact problem is? Perhaps give us instructions to follow to reproduce it?

Comment: The problem I am having is trying to string operations together ie:12 + 7 - 5 * 3. Right now it only does the operation of 12+7 and not doing the rest. @Scott Marcus

Comment: The instructions are as follows:
1. Your calculator is going to contain functions for all of the basic math operators
2.Create a new function operate that takes an operator and 2 numbers and then calls one of the functions

Comment: 3.Create a basic HTML calculator with buttons for each digit, each of the above functions and an “Equals” key.
4.Create the functions that populate the display when you click the number button
5.Make the calculator work! You’ll need to store the first number that is input into the calculator when a user presses an operator, and also save which operation has been chosen and then operate() on them when the user presses the “=” key
6. a) Users should be able to string together several operations and get the right answer: 12 + 7 - 5 * 3 etc.
b)round answers with long decimals
@Scott Marcus

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your code so that you will be able to display the value from `.value` to `display.innerHTML=result`
Edit:As mentioned by Scott Marcus if use there is no html in the string
then use `textContent`instead of `innerHtml` although it works fine in this example, but the two have some differences, so it is always good to keep good practice

```js
let op = document.getElementById("op");
let display = document.getElementById('display');
let calculte=document.getElementById("calculate")
clr();


//basic addition
function addition(numIni, numSub) {
  return parseFloat(numIni) + parseFloat(numSub);

}
//basic subtraction
function subtraction(numIni, numSub) {
  return parseFloat(numIni) - parseFloat(numSub);
}

//basic Multiplication
function multiply(numIni, numSub) {
  return parseFloat(numIni) * parseFloat(numSub);
}
//basic division
function divide(numIni, numSub) {
    if (numIni == 0 ||numSub == 0) {
        return "Can't do that";
      } 
        return parseFloat(numIni) / parseFloat(numSub);
}

//operator function
function operate(op,numIni,numSub) {
  switch (op) {
    case "+":
       result = addition(numIni, numSub);
      break;
    case "-":
      result = subtraction(numIni, numSub);
      break;
    case "*":
      result = multiply(numIni, numSub);
      break;
    case "/":
      result = divide(numIni, numSub);
  }
}
//button display functions
function disNum(val) {
  parseFloat(display.value += val); 
}

function disOp(val) {
  document.getElementById("display").value += val;
  return op = val;
}

function clr() {
  return document.getElementById("display").value = "";
}
calculte.addEventListener("click", equal)


function equal() {
let numIni = document.getElementById("n1").value;
let numSub = document.getElementById("n2").value;
console.log('clicked')
  let value = [op.value];
  if(value[0] != '') {
    // Separate numbers
    // Is there a valid operator?
    if(value.indexOf('+') != -1) op = '+';
    else if(value.indexOf('-') != -1) op = '-';
    else if(value.indexOf('*') != -1) op = '*';
    else if(value.indexOf('/') != -1) op = '/';
  
    var n1 =parseInt(numIni)
     var n2 = parseInt(numSub);
    if(n1&&n2!="") {
      // Set both variables
     operate(op,n1,n2);

      display.innerHTML=result
    } else {
      display.value = 'Error';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.container{
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-left: 20px;

}

#format {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="format">
  <input id="n1"/>
  <input id="n2"/>
  <br>
  <input id="op" maxlength="4" size="4"/>
  <div id="display">#########</div>
  
  <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML` when there is no HTML in the string (there are security and performance implications to it), instead use `.textContent`. Also, please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time, making your answer meaningless. Just insert your code, right here in your answer, using a Stack Snippet (the {} icon on the answer toolbar).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I used innerHTML because it works in this scenario. However, You are completely right, and I will keep this in mind for next time